# Can't use domain alias to log in to Google apps legacy free edition

Tags: google-workspace

I have been using Google apps free legacy edition for my domain (say- abc.com) last few years. Now, I want to add some of my colleagues to this service with a new domain as alias (xyz.com). After setting up the alias, the newly created accounts can not log in using the alias (person@xyz.com). How can I log in using the domain alias instead of primary domain?